# execute a command when extension ringing asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I used these commands for save CallerID in database :

```
exten => s,1,MYSQL(Connect connid localhost root 123456 CallerID) 
exten => s,2,Set(idcaller=${CALLERID(name)})
exten => s,3,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} INSERT INTO CallerID SET Num="${idcaller}")
exten => s,4,MYSQL(Disconnect ${connid})
```

Now i want to execute these commands when extension is ringing ... 
It means that first IVR works then the diall extension Id then these Commands have to work ...
where i have to put my commands ?
thanks alot .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do something when extension is ringing you have to use AMI interface and write your own application using it to detect ringing state and write it to database (or do anything else you like).

https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239

Answer (score 1):

You can't do anything on ringing state, it is not implemented in asterisk

You can do that when extension entered before dial - just put that before dial command like

```
exten => 100,1,MYSQL(Connect connid localhost root 123456 CallerID) 
exten => 100,2,Set(idcaller=${CALLERID(name)})
exten => 100,3,MYSQL(Query resultid ${connid} INSERT INTO CallerID SET Num="${idcaller}")
exten => 100,4,MYSQL(Disconnect ${connid})
exten => 100,n,Dial(SIP/100,,ro)
```

**NOTE**, MYSQL command is depricated. User func_odbc or realtime.